Why Python multithreading is not speeding things up?
#from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

import time

values = range(1,9999)

def dissect1(qq):
    adding    = sum(list1[qq:qq+100000])
    averaging = adding / len(list1[qq:qq+100000]) 
    return adding,averaging

def dissect2(qq):
    adding = sum(list2[qq:qq+100000])
    averaging = adding / len(list2[qq:qq+100000])
    return adding,averaging

    list1 = range(0, 99999999) # Two copies to speed things up?
    list2 = range(0, 99999999) # Two copies to speed things up?

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result1 = []
    result2 = []
    tic = time.time()

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as exe:
        result = exe.map(dissect1,range(1,5000))

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as exe:
        result2 = exe.map(dissect2,range(5000,9999))

    toc = time.time()
    print(f'Parallel execution, completed in {toc - tic} seconds')

    for v in values:
        a,b = dissect1(v)  

    tac = time.time()
    print(f'Serial execution, completed in {tac - toc} seconds')

Both parallel and serial execution resulted in about 27 seconds of run time.  Why is this so? I am expecting the parallel computation would be speedier.
Parallel execution, completed in 27.91899013519287 seconds
Serial execution, completed in 27.62840223312378 seconds

For operations which hold the GIL, no speedup should be expected from multithreading.

The amount of computation is very small compared to the multiprocessing overhead. Data needs to be sent to worker processes, pickled and unpickled which is expensive. Adding numbers is very cheap. You cannot speed such a computation using multiprocessing, nor multithreading in Python (the later is because of the GIL while the former is due to data transfer). There are many similar questions on StackOverflow. If you want to speed up such a computation and your numbers are not huge (eg. < 1e18), then please consider using Numpy instead of slow dynamic variable-sized integer objects.

By the way, your question states "Why Python multiprocessing is not speeding things up?" with the multiprocessing tags while you use multithreading in the code.

Thanks for the reply.  I am not even trying multiprocessing because the result was even worse, so GIL is not involved here. (I have edited the title of my post)  Adding numbers is very cheap and yet it still take about 27 seconds.  Actually my main task is to perform multiple very heavy accesses/computations on a single deque simultaneously , but to simplify my question post, I replaced it with a simple list.

I am having a deque of maxlen 5000.  I was hoping that I can adopt multi threading to perform many many accesses and computation on different portion of the deque at the same time.  Any suggestion to improve performance will be very much appreciated.  (I need the deque FIFO ability, so using Numpy is not suitable)

You cannot operate on the same object at the same time with multithreading especially because of the GIL. In fact, you cannot work on different objects either. The only way a multithreading code can be faster is when operations disable the GIL which is only possible when they are vectorized (ie. not executing any pure Python code nor manipulating any objects) or when doing IO operations. In all other cases, multithreading in Python is useless. Multiprocessing is more expensive due to data transfer as explained before, it only worth it if the computation are much more expensive.

Adding number in Python is very cheap compared to inter-process communication and pickling (mandatory to transfer data between CPython processes), but it is far more expensive than operating on native integers : it is generally about >=100 times slower than native operations. Numpy is indeed not great for a deque but in some case you can gather item per chunks so to have a deque of Numpy arrays. As it is, there is AFAIK no way to use parallelism to speed up the operation in the question working on Python objects. The key is not to use Python objects (this is how things works in CPython).

"GIL is not involved here" -- pardon? Multiprocessing avoids the GIL, multithreading does not; so in a threaded solution, the GIL is very much involved. If you can't move away from Python overall, at least move away from CPython when you need to have multiple threads operating on the same native-Python structure at the same time.

Thank you Charles, I stand corrected.  GIL is involved in multi-threading.

Thanks Richard.  I will take note this - In all other cases, multithreading in Python is useless.   So is there any way that I can process the content of the deque much faster?  At one instant, when the road traffic is heavy, some 398 data tuples are being appended to the deque within one second.  For meaningful work, I need to perform various computation on different segments of this deque and complete them within the next second.

As suggested in the above comment, "in some case you can gather item per chunks so to have a deque of Numpy array". Other modules like that might help. Otherwise, put it shortly, no, there is way to make that much faster. The best is not to use Python for that but native languages (e.g. C/C++/Rust). Python sucks for parallelism IMHO (and more generally for performance).

@JérômeRichard  Thank you.  I totally agree that C/C++ would be much faster.  Python was chosen because of Data Sci and ML.  I combed through the data source again.  At the peak of 31 Aug 2023, some 944 data tuples was added to the deque within a second.
